# Modify ServeContent file on the fly

Tags: go

I'm writing a simple web server to serve static files. Any HTML file being served needs to be modified "on the go" to include some HTML just before its closing `</body>` tag.

I achieved it with the below code and it works, however is there perhaps a **more efficient** way of doing it? I'm beginner in Go and this code needs to be super performant.

```golang
// error handling etc omitted for brevity

dir := http.Dir("my/path")

content, _ := dir.Open("my_file")

var bodyBuf strings.Builder
var contentBuf *bytes.Buffer

io.Copy(&bodyBuf, content)
defer content.Close()

if strings.HasSuffix("some/web/uri", ".html") {
    new_html_content := "<whatever></body>"
    bodyRpld := strings.Replace(bodyBuf.String(), "</body>", new_html_content, 1)
    contentBuf = bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(bodyRpld))
} else {
    contentBuf = bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(bodyBuf.String()))
}

d, _ := content.Stat()

http.ServeContent(w, r, "my/path", d.ModTime(), bytes.NewReader(contentBuf.Bytes()))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid creating large buffers for files that do no match your file-match pattern `*.html`, I would suggest using an `io.Reader` mechanism to pass-through files that you want to serve untouched. This avoids loading into memory potentially large assets (e.g. `100MB` non-html video files).

For files that do match your `html` check - your string-replace is probably fine as `.html` are typically small in size.

So try something like this:

```
dir := http.Dir("my/path")
content, err := dir.Open("my_file") // check error

var r io.ReadSeeker // for http.ServeContent needs

if !strings.HasSuffix("some/web/uri", ".html") {

    r = content // pass-through file content (avoid memory allocs)

} else {

    // similar to what you had before
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    n, err := b.ReadFrom(content) // check err
    defer content.Close()

    new_html_content := "<whatever></body>"
    newContent := strings.Replace(b.String(),
        "</body>", new_html_content, 1)

    r = bytes.NewReader([]byte(newContent))
}

d, _ := content.Stat()

http.ServeContent(w, r, "my/path", d.ModTime(), r)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. FYI: `ServeContent` expects a file with `seek` method, so I modified your code to pass a compatible interface: `var r io.ReadSeeker` and then `r = bytes.NewReader([]byte(newContent))`.

Comment: hmm, I cannot see that Go' `bytes.Buffer` module exposes a `seek` method.

Comment: correction `bytes.NewReader()` returns a `*bytes.Reader` which supports [Seek](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Reader.Seek)

Comment: @mlen108 FYI you could also call [http.ServeFile](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeFile) directly to serve a non-html file without having to open its contents.

Comment: I know of ServeFile existence. the issue with it is that it wraps potential errors into its own HTTP error responses which I do not want. it also checks if a passed named file is a dir which I do not want either. FYI `ServeFile` uses `serveContent` anyway (same as `ServeContent`).